# Convert PowerPoint Presentation to HTML with Office 2019 or Office 365

Tags: office365, office-interop, office-2007, export-to-html, powerpoint-interop

I have a code which converts the PowerPoint presentation to HTML using Office 2007. The code which runs on Office 2007 without a problem is as below:

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string source = "C:\\Temp\\testPPTX.pptx";
            string tempFile = "C:\\Temp\\mytest.html";

            Application app = new Application();
            Presentation presentation = app.Presentations.Open(source, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

            // Save the presentation as HTML
            presentation.SaveAs(tempFile, PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsHTML, MsoTriState.msoTriStateMixed);

            // Close the presentation and quit PowerPoint
            presentation.Close();
            app.Quit();

            Console.WriteLine("Conversion completed.");
        }
```

When I run the above code in the higher Office version such as Office 2019 or Office 365, I receive an error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Presentation (unknown
> member) : Invalid request.  Saving as an HTML presentation is not
> supported in this version of PowerPoint.'

[image]

Is there a way to convert the PowerPoint presentation HTML using the above code?

Comment: What PowerPoint version do you have installed?

Comment: Did you try to save the presentation manually in PowerPoint? Do you get the same results?

Comment: Have you also tried specifying another location (another disk) for the HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

As a possible workaround you can save slides as images and then construct the result HTML page based on these images. See [Slide.Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.export) method which exports a slide, using the specified graphics filter, and saves the exported file under the specified file name.

Comment: Astafie When I use the Slide.Export, the images are not in an accessible format and my requirement is to make the HTML accessible.

Comment: Do you get any notifications when you try to export a presentation to the HTML format manually?